# Equivalent expession of a complete $n$-partite graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification

I have just started learning Graph Theory and was going through basic terminologies and Graph operations. The author has asked one question(not in exercise)that have no book solutions.So I just wanted to make sure my answers and method of approach are correct.
The question is:
Suppose a complete $n$-partite graph $K_{p_1,p_2,....,p_n}$ is given.  Find an equivalent expression to this. To make this question a bit precise,we are required to represent it as a union of two or more bi-partite graphs. To do this,I take any two of the partite vertex sets of the graph and create a complete bipartite graph from this. We continue doing this for all pairs of partite sets of the $n$-partite graph and unite them so as to get  the $n$-partite graph.Thus,we get the final expression as:
$$K_{p_1,p_2,....,p_n}=\bigcup_{i\neq j} K_{p_i,p_j} $$

Comment: Can you share author/title?

Comment: Ronald J.Gould-Graph Theory-Benjamin Cummings

Comment: It asked the question in a paragraph on section-Elementary properties and Operations